# Lists size multiplication

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I'm new to Prolog and I'm trying to get my head around lists. The problem I'm struggling with is: 
Given numbers in the form of lists (1 : [x], 3: [x, x, x]), implement the **'times'** predicate /3. 
E.g.: times([x, x], [x, x, x], R).
R = [x, x, x, x, x, x].

The plus, and successor predicates where 2 previous points of the exercise. I know I'm not using the successor predicate, but it didn't seem that useful later on.

This is what i've tried so far

```
successor([], [x]).
successor([X|T], R) :- 
    append([X|T], [X], R).

plus(L1, L2, R) :- append(L1, L2, R).

times([], _, []).
times(_, [], []).
times([_], L, L).
times(L, [_], L).
times([_|T], L2, R) :- plus(L2, R, RN),
    times(T, L2, RN).
```

The output is: 
R is [].

Comment: What are you trying to do here with `append([X|T], [X], R)`?

Comment: successor([x, x], R) should produce R = [x, x, x]. So i'm just adding 1 more element just like the Head from the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make things too complicated here. You can define `successor` as:

```
successor(T, [x|T]).
```

We can define `plus/3` as:

```
plus([], T, T).
plus([x|R], S, [x|T]) :-
    plus(R, S, T).
```

This is more or less the implementation of `append/3`, except that here we check if the first list only contains `x`.

For `times/3` we know that if the first item is empty, the result is empty:

```
times([], _, []).
```

and for a `times/3` where the first item has shape `[x|R]`, we need to add the second item to the result of a call to `times/3` with `R`:

```
times([x|R], S, T) :-
    times(R, S, T1),
    plus(S, T1, T).
```

So putting it all together, we obtain:

```
successor(T, [x|T]).

plus([], T, T).
plus([x|R], S, [x|T]) :-
    plus(R, S, T).

times([], _, []).
times([x|R], S, T) :-
    times(R, S, T1),
    plus(S, T1, T).
```

Comment: Also, do you have any good IDE in mind for Prolog? I've configure VS Code, but I think there might something more professional out there.

Comment: @CosminStoian At this point an IDE seem overkill. I'm just using vim and https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ for exercises.

Comment: Ok. Thank you again!

Comment: Note that `times(A,B,[x])` is not terminating. Better solutions can be found under the tag [tag:successor-arithmetics]

Comment: @false: yes, I agree that it works not in all directions. A fast way to fix this would be iterating over the third parameter as well, such that at least termination is achieved.